# Word addin truncates the URL that we pass to SourceLocation

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Word addin truncates the URL that we pass `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://webserver/index.html#/addin"/>` to https://webserver/index.html it can't understand # and ? symbols
There is any solution to handle this?
Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20270) 64-bit

Comment: Is this an Angular or React add-in?

Comment: @RickKirkham Angularjs add-in

Comment: Can you use a routing strategy that does not require "#" in the URL?

Comment: @RickKirkham No. Problem exactly is that application is big and uses old strategy for a long time. Can't find any information in release why it has happened.

Comment: Try making https://webserver/index.html a UI-less page with a `<script>` tag that redirects to the Angular app.

Comment: @RickKirkham Even with redirect, it can't understand # symbol. When it redirects it cuts down anyway.

Comment: @RickKirkham It begins with new office UI update. For old version, it works fine. Only if pass location directly in console will work as expected, with warning 'tracking prevention blocked access'. Edge works fine without warnings.